# Comparing two date  of varchar and getdate

Tags: asp.net

I have a database table field named User_Created_Date of type Varchar.I want to write a query to fetch all records where the difference between Today's date and User_Created_Date is greater than 31 days

pls help

Answer (score 1):

Since your `VARCHAR` column's date format is `DD/MM/YY`, use:

```
select * from Your_Table
where DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(datetime, User_Created_Date, 3), GETDATE()) > 31;
```

Comment: Okay, but what's the meaning of each field? Is `09` the year, month, or day? :)

Comment: 09-day,05-month,10-year(dd/mm/yy)